# Word 2016: total page numbers of multiple sections

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am writing a document, which has cover page, contents pages, many chapters, and appendix. I put "odd section break" to contents, every chapters and appendix. To make page numbering, I could pages such as "i, ii, iii ..." to contents and appendix pages.

The problem is chapter pages. I want to make "x of y" format, where x starts from 1 at the chapter 1 and contineously increases. For y, total pages from the chapter 1 to end of final chapter.

For example, I have 10 chapters which has total 512 pages(please remember that cover, contents and appendix pages must be excluded). Then every chapter page must be shown as 12 of 512, 123 of 512 like that.

I think "x" value would be fine if I turn on the "link to previous seciton", but I have no idea to make total pages of specified section.

Answer (score 2):

### To get the number of pages in a Section, use the SectionPages field.

Note that this refers to the number of pages in the Word section which may or may not be your Chapter.

If you have a Section break before each new chapter, and those are the only section breaks, this works. If you have more section breaks, something more complex is needed.

Here is my writing on [Pagination Fields](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination).

### If you only want to eliminate your front matter from your page total, you need to restart numbering after your front matter. This requires a section break.

The methods for doing this are explained in depth in Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on [Numbering Front Matter](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm).

The second section restarts numbering at 1. This is done in the Format Page Numbers dialog that you can reach through Insert > Page Number. This is *only* done in the second section.

For the "y" part of your page x of y formulation, you need to use a calculation field. So instead of the NUMPAGES field alone (which shows 512) you use a field like this:

```
{ = NUMPAGES - 11 }
```

If you need the 11 to be dynamic because the number of pages in the front matter may change, write back in a comment, because this is possible as well, but more complicated.

If you would like more information...

- Here is [my article on the Microsoft site on editing fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).
- Here is my writing on [Page Numbers in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers).
- Here is my writing on [Pagination Fields in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination).

If you need more help, please comment and I will try to explain more here rather than through links.

Comment: I would be interested to know how to do it if the first section size might vary.

Comment: @Legisey - For ignoring your front matter in the Page Total, you would place a PAGE field on the last page of your first section and color it white so it will be invisible. Bookmark it. Use that bookmark instead of the 11. `{ = NUMPAGES - { myPageBookmark } }`